# How to change DIV background when i hover a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I change a div's background image when I hover few links, I mean if I hover over link1 there is one background, link2 an other background and so on.

```
<div style="background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat right; ">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Can it be done with JavaScript, or jQuery, or simple CSS trick?

CAN ANYONE TELL ME PLEASE WHAT I AM DOING WRONG????

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.background-changer').on('mouseover', 'a', function () {

    var background = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-background') + "')";

    $('.background-changer').css('background-image', background)
});
</script>
</head>

<body>



<div style="background:url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/01/01/article-2255449-16B57005000005DC-878_964x641.jpg) no-repeat right;" class="background-changer"> 

 <a href="#" data-background="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/1298643948/FranceFlag_svg.png">Link 1</a>
 <a href="#" data-background="http://cdn.londonandpartners.com/visit/london-organisations/houses-of-parliament/63950-640x360-london-icons2-640.jpg">Link 2</a>
 <a href="#" data-background="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/01/01/article-2255449-16B57005000005DC-878_964x641.jpg">Link 3</a> 
 <a href="#" data-background="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/godrick/godrick1002/godrick100200011/6503920-tower-bridge-london-england-uk-europe-illuminated-at-dusk.jpg">Link 4</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @F.Hauri How so? There's no parent selector in CSS

Comment: How? can you show an example?

Comment: why use selector(id) if its a parent?

Comment: check out my answer, and see if its what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data-attributes

**jQuery:**

```
$('.background-changer').on('mouseover', 'a', function () {

    var background = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-background') + "')";

    $('.background-changer').css('background-image', background)
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat right;" class="background-changer"> 

    <a href="#" data-background="image1.jpg">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-background="image2.jpg">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-background="image3.jpg">Link 3</a> 
    <a href="#" data-background="image4.jpg">Link 4</a>

</div>
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/a9ZRe/1/)

Comment: Could also use `$(".background-changer").on("mouseover", "a", function () { });` so that there's only one event binding. Not too important, but just thought I'd point it out

Comment: I wouldn't use data attributes unless you don't care about browsers that don't support new HTML 5 attributes.

Comment: Data-attributes weren't included until the HTML5 specification, but they work universally! http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: @sgroves The only time that doesn't apply is if you don't use the HTML5 doctype. Otherwise, that comment makes no sense

Comment: Can ou please look at my question again? I tried our example, but i cannot manage to make it work on m page... what wrong?

Comment: Try putting the JavaScript just before the end of the <body> tag, or wrap it in $(document).ready(...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can here's code:

```
$('a').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).parent().css('background', new_background);
});
```

This is using `jQuery`, you select all the `anchors` and subscribe to the mouseover event. Then you apply new `CSS` background attribute value on the parent of the element being hovered. You can use `mouseout()` to bring back the old background, but you would get some flickering effect when moving from anchor to `anchor` and so you can use a timeout to revert the background. Just FYI make the selector more specific because currently it applies to all anchors in your document. Restrict it to all anchors inside your div by giving the div an ID or some specific class.

Comment: And `.mouseout()` to bring back the old background (If he wants to)

Comment: @RyanB You're free to submit your own, better method if you feel this is suboptimal or could be achieved better without jQuery.

Comment: @user1978483 I added some explanation for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/LJldn

Use data attributes to declaratively set the background color

```
<div style="background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat right; ">
  <a href="#" data-bg="yellow">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-bg="green">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-bg="#000">Link 3</a>
</div>

$("a").on("mouseover",function(){

  $(this).parent().css("background-color",$(this).attr("data-bg"));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selector a').hover(function() {
        var targetBG = $(this).attr('id');

        $('.selector').css({'background':'url('+targetBG+'.jpg) no-repeat right'});
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="selector" style="background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat right; ">
      <a href="#" id="image1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" id="image2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" id="image3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" id="image4">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm betting it's because `class` isn't a safe attribute to use - it can contain many classes and therefore not work as a place to store the file name. Didn't downvote, but I wouldn't use `class` for something like this

Comment: I dont understan why its not working on my website... I will try more, to see whats wrong

Comment: @user1978483 you need to wrap this code with `document.ready()`, i've updated my answer, check it out again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One simple way is to give your div an ID and each link an ID:

```
<div id="parent" style="background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat right; ">
  <a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a id="link3" href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a id="link4" href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Then use JavaScript with jQuery:

```
$('#parent a').hover(function() {
  var color;
  switch($(this).attr('id')) {
    case 'link1': color = 'red';    break;
    case 'link2': color = 'black';  break;
    case 'link3': color = 'yellow'; break;
    case 'link4': color = 'green';
  }

  $(this).parent().css({ 'background': color });
});
```

Obviously, use IDs that make sense.

You could also give each background color a CSS class and assign those to the parent on hover, or use a multitude of other solutions. It's all about figuring out what makes the most sense for your application. If you're going to have a ton of links, you'll want to use a more dynamic solution, perhaps giving the links IDs such as `link_red` and `link_yellow`, then pulling the colors from the IDs in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>

    function chgBG(e){
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(newImage.jpg)';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="focusArea" onmousemove="getPos(event)">
        <p>Mouse Over This Text And Background will change!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bk variable will save the default color, then applying the hover function changes the color. then on mouse leave you replace with the default color

```
 <div style="background: silver; ">
      <a href="#black">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#green">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#red">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#gray">Link 4</a>
    </div>



 var bk = $('div').css('background');
    $('a').hover(function(){
        $('div').css('background',$(this).attr('href').replace("#",''));
        // or 
        // $(this).parent().css('background',$(this).attr('href').replace("#",''));

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
onmouseover="this.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(newimage.gif)'"
```

if u preffer pure js.

The parentNode gets the above element of the one u use onmouseover, in this case u add onmouseover on the a elements to get the above element of it.

Comment: Inline JavaScript is very messy

Comment: yeah, says the jquery guy.

Answer (score -2):

First off you shouldn't use inline styles if you can avoid it.

```
<div class="some-class-name">
  <a class="link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a class="link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a class="link3" href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a class="link4" href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>

.some-class-name {
    background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat right;
}
```

Use jQuery to make the background image change by adding/removing a class to the containing div on hover of each link.

```
$(".link1").hover(
  function () {
  $(this).parent().addClass("link1-bg");
},
  function () {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("link1-bg");
}
);

$(".link2").hover(
      function () {
      $(this).parent().addClass("link2-bg");
    },
      function () {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("link2-bg");
    }
    );

$(".link3").hover(
      function () {
      $(this).parent().addClass("link3-bg");
    },
      function () {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("link3-bg");
    }
    );

$(".link4").hover(
      function () {
      $(this).parent().addClass("link4-bg");
    },
      function () {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("link4-bg");
    }
    );
```

Your css classes which will be added by the above jQuery code.

```
.link1-bg {
    background: url(link1-bg.jpg) no-repeat right;
}

.link2-bg {
    background: url(link2-bg.jpg) no-repeat right;
}

.link3-bg {
    background: url(link3-bg.jpg) no-repeat right;
}

.link4-bg {
    background: url(link4-bg.jpg) no-repeat right;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of JavaScript. What if he has 100 links?

Comment: No mention was made in the original question of having a large number of links but yes, if there was a large number then it would be better to use a nice looping method to do this in jQuery. What I've posted will work though, and would be fine to use imo on a small number of links. Some harsh downvoting for a valid answer :-(

Comment: Of course it's "valid", but that doesn't mean it should be upvoted. If people don't agree with it, sometimes it's downvoted. You can easily reorganize this code more efficiently so you don't need to have multiple event bindings, store things better, and handle the whole operation differently. I didn't downvote nor upvote, as I'm neutral about it all